# How to use html5 form validation properties using struts2 UI tags

Tags: html, forms, struts2

I want to use HTML5 form validations like 'required', in struts2 UI tag . I also have checked struts2 core jar file which shows that dynamic attribute is true for s:textbox. but if i use like `<S:textbox name="username" required>`, it is throwing error.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
<s:textbox name="username" required="required" />
```

Works perfectly in my case.

You can also use other html5 attributes in a similar way. 
eg. placeholder="placeholder value" , etc.

Answer (score 0):

The attributes must have a value. So required will not work but required="" will not cause an issue.

Comment: There is no error when using format required="" or required="true", but it is not validating the empty fields and form submission happens for null values

Comment: Can you please clarify your further issue? However regarding the struts2 tags there must be a value for every attribute.

Comment: I need to use form validation for required field. When i declare it as equired="" or required="true", there is no code error, but it submits the form without any form validation. (server validation occurs if i submit empty box)

Comment: The correct forms are : (required, required="", or required="required") the required attribute has to do with client side validation only it has nothing to do with struts2, excepting that the struts2 UI tags don't play nice with attributes without values. If things aren't working create a plain HTML form and experiment to see if the client side validation is working as expected. Test with different browsers too.

Answer (score 0):

This is the only way I have made it work in IE FF and Chrome

```
<input type="text" name="u.lName" required value='<s:property value="u.lName"'/>'/>
```